# JPA: User-Entity contains another User-Entity

Tags: jpa

In my domain model i have a **user** entity, which contains another **user** (composite pattern). When i want to persist the user, i get an error which says something like "Data too long for column...". This happens because the contained user is tried to be stored as a BLOB. I want the ID of the contained user to be stored - not the whole object as a BLOB.

What kind of annotation must i user in the case? The cardinality is 1 : 0..1 - so a user can contain another user.

here is the code ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="flex_app_user")
public class User implements Serializable {

private User client;

public User(){

}

@OneToOne
public User getClient() {
    return client;
}
}
```

... and the problem resulted by a change in the datamodel. The correct annotation is OneToOne. And everything works fine.

kind regards,
Jochen

Comment: @JB Nizet -> I've put the code in my first post

Answer (score 2):

The annotation must be [`@OneToOne`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html).

Comment: I already have annotated it with \@OneToOne. This had no effect. Do i have to use the \@Column Annotation to add further information?

Comment: Show us the code of the entity. Show us what you're doing (i.e. the code) with the entities. Tell us what you expect this code to do, and what it does instead. To do that, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the composite pattern can you use `(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` on the relation ship used?

Comment: Does that affect anything concerning the persistence? The problem is that the complete object is stored as a BLOB. That is not neccessary. Just the userId should be right and enough.